# how to overcome writing this "datetime.date(2016, 3, 31)" to the file

Tags: python, date, datetime, web-scraping

`to_date` is a string in the format `Month day, Year`, e.g. May 31, 2016:

```
to_date=parser.parse(to_date).date()
list.append(to_date)
```

Sample output:

> '44', 'NOW()', datetime.date(2016, 3, 31), '0', ''

Expected output:

> '44', 'NOW()','2016-3-31', '0', ''

Answer (score 2):

Format the date to a string using [`.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
to_date = parser.parse(to_date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
list.append(to_date)
```